# Ignoring CMake cached variable

Tags: cmake

How can I force CMake to ignore cached value? I want to require the caller to pass variable each time, for example

```sh
cmake .. -DSOME_VAR=value
```

and if I call CMake like

```sh
cmake ..
```

without SOME_VAR I want that this piece of CMake code to fail:

```
if (NOT DEFINED)
    message(FATAL_ERROR " SOME_VAR is missing.")
endif()
```

It seems that unset(SOME_VAR CACHE) doesn't do what I expect. I actually don't care for cached variables at all, I don't mind if it slower.

Comment: re-run plain `cmake <path>` to update the file list.

Comment: "I want to require the caller to pass variable each time" - This opposites the natural way of using CMake, when re-running `cmake` uses the same value of a parameter as passed the first time, unless that parameter is explicitly set in the command line. Note also, that `cmake` could be re-run internally during the build, e.g. when the file, passed to `configure_file`, is changed. I think the best way is create **your own script**, which would process its arguments as you want (as a developer) and call `cmake` with appropriate `-D` (set variable) and `-U` (unset variable) options.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by testing for the `SOME_VAR` **before** the `project` statement, i.e. your root `CMakeLists.txt` should contain a piece of code like this:

```
#very first lines of a CMakeLists.txt
#note: the test must be done **BEFORE** project statement

if(NOT SOME_VAR)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "SOME_VAR must be defined in command line")
endif()

project(project_requiring_some_var_in_cmd_line)

#the rest of your CMakeLists.txt
```

Also, as already pointed out, note that this is not the natural way of using CMake. It may be beneficial if you explained the problem you are trying to solve.